# where in rails to put common text used by lots of files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

We have lots of templates that use a common paragraph of text (the description of our company services).  The paragraph is currently duplicated among 10 different view templates.

Where should I create a variable like 'company_services_description' that I can use in all the different templates (to DRY it up).

Would defining it in `application_controller.rb` be the way to go?

Or perhaps would `config/application.rb` would be the right spot?

Answer (score 3):

It depends how long the text it. I would suggest either storing the text in a partial and using it in your templates as follows:

```
<%= render "shared/company_services_description_partial" %>
```

or using an application helper method that you can call wherever you need it.

```
module ApplicationHelper

  def company_services_description
    "This is our company services description"
  end

end
```